# Can't Access Checkout Page

Tags: magento2, checkout, attribute-options, frontend-error

I tried to access my checkout page, but it returns blank page, and when i checked the error log, i got this message:

> [Thu Mar 29 10:30:46.928754 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17712]
>   [client x.x.x.x:x] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP
>   Deprecated:  The each() function is deprecated. This message will be
>   suppressed on further calls in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 81\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Attribute\Source\Country::getAllOptions()
>   must be compatible with
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table::getAllOptions($withEmpty
>   = true, $defaultValues = false) in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/Address/Attribute/Source/Country.php
>   on line 17\n', referer: mydomain.com

Comment: which php version you are using ?

Comment: You may be use "**php-7.2**" that why you getting this error.You should down grade **7.1**  or **7.0**